# C# - How do I get cumulative distance\time between Suburb objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my final code edit to this question. This was the best solution I was able to come up with. I'm still open to other solutions if anyone has them.

I was looking for advice as to the best way to find the cumulative time or distance between two **non-consecutive** suburbs, in a linear chain of suburbs, if I have the distance of time/distance between each one. I expressed the original problem as:

> I know the time it takes to drive between Suburb A and Suburb B,
>   Suburb B and Suburb C, Suburb C and Suburb D etc. How can I find the time it takes to drive between any two
>   non-consecutive suburbs (Suburb C and Suburb G for example).

Since it was classified as too broad, I have worked on it and come up with this solution. I am interested as to whether there is a more efficient or future-proof solution.

Given a suburb class as defined below:

```
public class Suburb
{
    public string name;
    public int index;
    public double timeToNextSuburb;
    public double kilometresToNextSuburb;
    public double timeToPreviousSuburb;
    public double kilometresToPreviousSuburb;
    public Suburb(int index, string name, double time, double kilometres)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.index = index;
        this.timeToNextSuburb = time;
        this.kilometresToNextSuburb = kilometres;
    }
}
```

and a list of suburb objects as defined below:

```
 public static class SuburbManager
    {
                public static List<Suburb> InitializeSuburbs()
    {
        var baseList = new List<Tuple<string, int, double>>{
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("Start",0,0),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("a",6,6.4),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("b",5,4.8),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("c",8,6.3),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("d",5,2.4),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("e",6,4.7),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("f",7,6.8),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("g",3,2.5),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("h",3,3.2),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("i",3,2.8),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("j",7,6.3),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("k",4,4.0),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("l",3,3.4),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("m",3,3.3),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("n",4,3.0),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("o",0,0),
                new Tuple<string,int,double>("p",0,0)
            };
        var suburbList = baseList.Select((t, i) => new Suburb(i - 1, t.Item1, t.Item2, t.Item3)).ToList();
        for(var i = 1; i < suburbList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            suburbList[i].timeToPreviousSuburb = suburbList[i - 1].timeToNextSuburb;
            suburbList[i].kilometresToPreviousSuburb = suburbList[i - 1].kilometresToPreviousSuburb;
        }
        return suburbList;
    }
```

and the following methods:

```
        public static double GetSuburbTime(string suburbName1, string suburbName2)
    {
        int suburb1ID, suburb2ID;
        if ((suburb1ID = GetSuburbID(suburbName1)) < (suburb2ID = GetSuburbID(suburbName2)))
        {
            return InitializeSuburbs().Where(suburbs => suburbs.index >= suburb1ID && suburbs.index < suburb2ID).Sum(suburb => suburb.timeToNextSuburb);
        }
        return InitializeSuburbs().Where(suburbs => suburbs.index >= suburb2ID && suburbs.index < suburb1ID).Sum(suburb => suburb.timeToNextSuburb);
    }
public static int GetSuburbID(string suburbName)
    {
        return InitializeSuburbs().First(suburb => suburb.name == suburbName).index;
    }

    public static string GetCurrentSuburb(string suburbName1, string suburbName2, double minutesElapsed)
    {
        int suburb1ID, suburb2ID;
        List<Suburb> suburbRange;
        if((suburb1ID = GetSuburbID(suburbName1)) < (suburb2ID = GetSuburbID(suburbName2)))
        {
            suburbRange = InitializeSuburbs().Where(suburbs => suburbs.index >= suburb1ID && suburbs.index < suburb2ID).OrderBy(suburbs => suburbs.index).ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < suburbRange.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (minutesElapsed < suburbRange.GetRange(0, i + 1).Sum(suburb => suburb.timeToNextSuburb))
                {
                    return suburbRange[i].name;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            suburbRange = InitializeSuburbs().Where(suburbs => suburbs.index >= suburb2ID && suburbs.index < suburb1ID).OrderByDescending(suburbs => suburbs.index).ToList();
            for(var i = 0; i < suburbRange.Count(); i++)
            {
                if(minutesElapsed < suburbRange.GetRange(0, i + 1).Sum(suburb => suburb.timeToPreviousSuburb))
                {
                    return suburbRange[i].name;
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Sorry for the huge code blocks, but the GetTime method essentially gets the sub-array with the desired suburbs in it and counts up the time between them, and the GetCurrentSuburb method checks how many minutes have passed while driving, and, given the suburb that you started at and the suburb you will finish in, gives you what suburb you are currently in.

Since this is such a lot of code for a small problem, if there is a simpler way of doing this, I would appreciate any feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: If you know the time from Point A to Point B and the time from Point B to Point C, wouldn't it follow that the time to Point A, Point B, and Point C would be simple addition? If not, I misunderstand what you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed, that is what is occuring in the GetSuburbTime method. I need it to run backwards as well, from Point C to Point A, and also be able to extrapolate the current position based on how many minutes have passed, which is done in the GetCurrentSuburb method.

Comment: Got it. From Physics, Distance = Velocity * Time. I can give you a more detailed answer if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, the fact that I have the kilometres in there is just in case I need to measure distances later on. The Google Maps times are more reliable as they automatically include traffic lights, speed limits, and the like. What I'm really asking for is how to improve the design from an OOP perspective, as I'm sure most people would agree having to store previousSuburb and nextSuburb type variables is less than optimal. The current setup does allow me to add additional values later as it takes care of indexing for me, but it seems like there is a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could solve this using a Graph and you can calculate the [shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) between two suburbs using the [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm, also it possible to pre-calculate all the cost of any pair of suburbs using the [Floyd–Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm.